# ClassCastException String to Object[]

Tags: java, classcastexception

I am using the following code:

```
{
    // ...
    String[] roles = new String[resultList.size()];
    int i=0;
    for (Iterator<Object[]> iter = resultList.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
        roles[i] = new String();
        Object[] objArr = iter.next();
        roles[i] = objArr[0].toString();
        i++;
    }
return roles;
}
```

However, I get a `ClassCastException` saying cannot cast from java.lang.String to Object[].

Comment: can you provide the stacktrace

Comment: String is an Object but all the Objects are not Strings. You can not cast Object to String.

Comment: which line throws the ClassCastException?

Comment: Does it really say "cannot cast from java.lang.String to Object" (this should not be a problem), or "cannot cast from java.lang.String to Object[]"?

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
Line 5 in the code throws Exception

Comment: `[Ljava.lang.Object` is `Object[]` In this case, make sure that there are actually `Object[]`s in `resultList`, and not strings.

Comment: I would guess that resultList contains Strings and not Object[]s

Comment: In that case,can I just convert my resultList to a String [] ?

Comment: try (Iterator<String> iter = resultList.iterator(); iter.hasNext();)... or better, post the code where resultList is instantiated

Comment: @user2811968, a stacktrace or more details would be really useful in order to help you. But I updated my answer with some comments to help you. If it was useful, consider accept the answer.

Comment: Well, you cannot cast from java.lang.String to Object[].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
{
    // ...
    String[] roles = new String[resultList.size()];
    int i=0;
    for (Iterator<String> iter = resultList.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {            
        roles[i] = iter.next();
        i++;
    }
    return roles;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to convert an `Object` list to a `String` array:

```
    // Create an object list and add some strings to it
    List<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<>();
    objectList.add("A");
    objectList.add("B");
    objectList.add("C");

    // Create an String array with the same size of the object list
    String[] stringArray = new String[objectList.size()];

    // Iterate over the object list to fill the string array, invoking toString() in each object to get a textual representation from it
    for (int i = 0; i < objectList.size(); i++) {
        Object object = objectList.get(i);
        stringArray[i] = object.toString();
    }

    // Iterate over the string array to print the strigs
    for (String string : stringArray) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
```

Comment: It's a list of `String`, and he's trying to (implicitly) cast the elements to `Object[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make this:

```
Object[] objArr = iter.next();
```

Into this:

```
  String[] objArr = (String[]) iter.next();
```